# Purpose of gwt browser plug-in

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, web, vaadin

What is purpouse of GWT browser plug-in? Please help me to understand. And why browser can receive java object from server? Gwt tecnology must work without plugins.

Comment: The plugin is *only* for faster edit-refresh-debug. When you want to build something to work for users, compile to actual JavaScript.

Comment: It would really help if people who downvote, also take out time to add a comment explaining whats wrong with the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GWT browser plugin is only for development mode to allow JAVA/GWT Developers to debug code.**

Once GWT code is compiled in javascript and deployed into production webserver the browser plugin is not required. So users of your gwt website need not install any gwt plugin in their browser.

Dev Mode -http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideDevMode

Production Mode - http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying.html

Answer (score 1):

GWT browser plugin helps the browser to recognize URL like `*?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`.

Then, when you do an action on a GWT component on a page which has this URL pattern,  the plugin will tell the browser that it must not try to execute some javascript code but forward the event to the **code server** (that you must have previously started) which will in turn compile the code on the fly and execute it.

The idea is that if you change a small piece of code, you can just reload the web page without having to recompile the whole project : your changes will be recompiled on the fly.

Here is a [link to the relevant part of the official documentation.](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideDevMode)